# Date column with default date with hour and minute

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I want to add a date field to my entity which saves **current date** by default. Works fine, except it saves with "yyyy-MM-dd" format. But I need to save hour and minute also.

```
@Column(name = "createDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date createDate = new Date();
```

I know that SimpleDateFormat can format any date, but following statement would fail because TemporalType is not applicable for a String.

```
public Date date = new Date;

@Column(name = "createDate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) // <- wrong
private String createDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss").format(this.date);
```

How can I both create a date field and format it like "**2019-09-16 21:48**"?

Comment: you can write customDateTimeConverter as well using AttributeConverter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `String` or `Date`, use Java 8 `LocalDateTime`

```java
@Column(name = "createDate")
private LocalDateTime createDate = LocalDateTime.now();
```

and also it depends on SQL server which you are using,

In case of MySQL or POSTGRESQL there is a `timestamp` datatype

so try changing your column datatype

```
create table IAmTable (
//Content
create_date timestamp (or) createDate timestamp
);
```